# How to search for a part of attribute value in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, split, match

How can I get a part from all **data attribute values**, **count them** and **change background color of the element**. I have set an example on **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zkrqmeab/)**

For example:

The attribute is called **data-search**. The value is set to **search_12** (the number is to ID the element).

I'm trying to find **search_** everywhere in the body (I'd like to target everything within the body and no a specific section) when clicking the button.
So, there is a lot of elements that have the same **data attribute**, but the difference, is that, the value has a number at the end that changes for identification purpose.

*If it is possible, I'd like to use split method since is faster than match() or RegExp(). Otherwise, feel free to answer your way.*

This is what I have.

**JS**

```
$( "button" ).on( "click", function() {

      var search = $( "body" ).children( "*" ).attr( "data-search" )

      var results = search.split( 'search_' ).length - 1;  

      $('.count-results').text( results )

});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="section">
   <button type="button">Search</button>
</div>

<div class="section">
   <section>
      <div>
         <h1>Please <span class="span" data-search="search_21">find me</span></h1>
         <p class="para">Search for data</p>
      </div>
   </section>

   <article> 
      <section>
         <div>
            <h1>Find the next element's data</h1>
            <p data-search="search_400" class="para">
            Find me too
            </p>
         </div>
      </section>
   </article>

   <details open>
      <address>
        Written by <a href="#" data-search="search_1">Jon Doe</a>.<br> 
        Visit us at:<br>
        Example.com<br>
        Box <span class="number" data-search="search_anything">564</span>, 
        Disneyland<br>
        USA
     </address>
   </details>
</div>

<div class="section">
   <p>The string of <b>search_</b> was found:</p>
   <div>
      <span class="count-results"></span> times
   </div> 
</div>
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Attribute Starts With Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/):

```js
$( "button" ).on( "click", function() {
  var results = $('[data-search^="search_"]');
  
  results.css('background', 'red');      
  
  $('.count-results').text(results.length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section">
   <button type="button">Search</button>
</div>

<div class="section">
   <section>
      <div>
         <h1>Please <span class="span" data-search="search_21">find me</span></h1>
         <p class="para">Search for data</p>
      </div>
   </section>

   <article> 
      <section>
         <div>
            <h1>Find the next element's data</h1>
            <p data-search="search_400" class="para">
            Find me too
            </p>
         </div>
      </section>
   </article>

   <details open>
      <address>
        Written by <a href="#" data-search="search_1">Jon Doe</a>.<br> 
        Visit us at:<br>
        Example.com<br>
        Box <span class="number" data-search="search_anything">564</span>, 
        Disneyland<br>
        USA
     </address>
   </details>
</div>

<div class="section">
   <p>The string of <b>search_</b> was found:</p>
   <div>
      <span class="count-results"></span> times
   </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Great answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just use the appropriate [CSS Attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

> `[attr^=value]`
>
> Represents an element with an attribute name of attr
>   whose value is prefixed (preceded) by value.

So in your example you would use something along the lines of

```
$("[data-search^='search_']")
```

The collection would then hold all elements that had a data-search attribute that was prefixed with `search_`

Demo

```js
$("button").click(function(){
  var count = $("[data-search^='search_']").length;
  $(".count-results").text(count);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section">
   <button type="button">Search</button>
</div>

<div class="section">
   <section>
      <div>
         <h1>Please <span class="span" data-search="search_21">find me</span></h1>
         <p class="para">Search for data</p>
      </div>
   </section>

   <article> 
      <section>
         <div>
            <h1>Find the next element's data</h1>
            <p data-search="search_400" class="para">
            Find me too
            </p>
         </div>
      </section>
   </article>

   <details open>
      <address>
        Written by <a href="#" data-search="search_1">Jon Doe</a>.<br> 
        Visit us at:<br>
        Example.com<br>
        Box <span class="number" data-search="search_anything">564</span>, 
        Disneyland<br>
        USA
     </address>
   </details>
</div>

<div class="section">
   <p>The string of <b>search_</b> was found:</p>
   <div>
      <span class="count-results"></span> times
   </div> 
</div>
```